# Global Menu shrinks appname

Tags: unity, customization, globalmenu

So this is not a question on how to have the Global Menu always visible, but instead, how to make the Global Menu to show the full appname.

If it's too long it gets faded out:

[image: unity panel screenshot]

How would I be able to change that, so that the full appname + the whole menu gets displayed in the top menu, just like in OS X?

Comment: It shrinks like this only on mouse hover and while not maximized. Okay, let's imagine that it will work as you expect. Also imagine 800*600 or 1024*768 screen resolution and "An App With Very Very Long Name". What will it look like?..

Comment: Since I have my global menu always shown, it is always shrunken. Besides that I am using a  1080p screen. So why does  Ubuntu not recognize that my screen is big enough to have the name "Terminal" written out and still have enough space for the menu. I mean, I have no problem that it gets shrinked if the name is too long, but shrinking names like "Terminal" while the there is uge space of nothingness just makes  it look [weird](http://i.imgur.com/CDInWDc.png) and clustered.

Comment: Still no answer, this was also asked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/809224/configure-unity-to-show-the-full-app-name-in-menu-bar).  If I can't tweak it to show the name regardless of length, maybe I can change the space reserved for the name -- instead of a paltry 80 or so pixels, I'd be happy if the menu started at, say, 200 or even 300 pixels from the left edge of the screen.