# Configure Unity to show the full app name in menu bar

Tags: unity, customization, menu-bar

Is it possible to configure the Unity menu bar to not truncate the app name in the menu bar.

If that is not possible, can the length allowed for the app name be adjusted?

*Edit*

I am trying to find a way that would show "Google Chrome" without being truncated with the fade effect on the menu bar.  I prefer having the menu always visible, but also see the app name (similar to on a Mac).

[image: Screen snippet showing problem]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot please? Because here it is not truncated... http://imgur.com/9NMAeNt

Comment: This question was asked here as well: http://askubuntu.com/questions/774274/global-menu-shrinks-appname